# Using reflection class in PHP also unable to access private property

Tags: php, reflection

How to access private property values outside the class? I also tried using reflection in PHP.

```
<?php
namespace TDD;
class Receipt {

    public $user_id = 1;
    private $pending_amount = 45;   

    
    public function total(array $items = []){   
    $items[] = $this->pending_amount;
       return array_sum($items);
    }

    public function tax($amount,$tax){
        return $amount * $tax;
    }
    
    public function pending()
    {
        return $this->pending_amount = 45;
    }
    
    public function addTaxPending($tax){
        return $this->pending_amount * $tax;
    }
}


$class = new \ReflectionClass('TDD\Receipt');
$myProtectedProperty = $class->getProperty('pending_amount');
$myProtectedProperty->setAccessible(true);
$myInstance = new Receipt();
$myProtectedProperty->setValue($myInstance, 99);

echo $myInstance->pending_amount;


?>
```

Error:
`
$ php src/Receipt.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property TDD\Receipt::$pending_amount in C:\xampp\htdocs\all_scripts\PHPUnit_By_siddhu\src\Receipt.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\all_scripts\PHPUnit_By_siddhu\src\Receipt.php on line 48

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property TDD\Receipt::$pending_amount in C:\xampp\htdocs\all_scripts\PHPUnit_By_siddhu\src\Receipt.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\all_scripts\PHPUnit_By_siddhu\src\Receipt.php on line 48
`
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vKVm.png)

How can I solve it? Looking for your valuable solutions.

Comment: Post error as text, not as image.

Comment: _"How to access private property values outside the class?"_ You don't, that's the point of a private property. If you need to get the value, you write a public getter method that returns it. If you need to set the value, you write a public setter method that takes the new value as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the PHP manual for ReflectionProperty::setAccessible](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php):

> Enables access to a protected or private property via the ReflectionProperty::getValue() and ReflectionProperty::setValue() methods.

Calling `setAccessible` has no effect on access to the property via normal PHP syntax, only via that ReflectionProperty object.

So this line is still accessing a private property:

```
echo $myInstance->pending_amount;
```

You need to instead access it via your reflection object:

```
echo $myProtectedProperty->getValue($myInstance);
```

Comment: How can I access method? @IMSoP

Comment: You can invoke methods like this https://pastebin.com/qFHXXMng